# How to train a recommender system to improve the customer class?

Tags: recommender-system, data-science-model

Considering the definition of a recommending system

> A **recommender system**, is a subclass of information filtering system that seeks to predict the "rating" or "preference" a user would give to an item. They are primarily used in commercial applications. ***Source:Wikipedia***.

it is condsidered into a retail problem having two datasets:

- shop - customers characteristics
- historical transaction about items with their properties.

I am wondering the following question about this kind of problems:

- **Question 1:** By recommending products from similar stores could this algorithm guarantee that the stores are going to get more sales?
- **Question 2:** Lets say that we know if a shop is classified into high|Medium|Low customer(we have that variable), In this case, in a general level how could we do a recommendation of products that takes into an account that we expect to convert all shops as much as possible into a high customers.